# password protected site, but upon logging in it keeps asking for login

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd

```
user:user
```

upon logging in, it keeps asking for loggin credentials.

Comment: Are you testing on local network?  Are you sure there are no proxies or other things in the way that may be confusing things?

Answer (score 2):

The .htpasswd file needs to contain the password for the `user` in the correct encoded format.

```
user:<encoded password>
```

You can use the following command to generate the file

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd user
```

Comment: it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? The command I gave? The original problem?
Is there any activity appearing in the access log for the server?